What is the deal with Sync and NonSync in @realm/expo-template?
I'm moving my first steps into react native development and I'm trying to integrate realm for storage, both local and cloud.
I'm going with expo so I downloaded the template from the realm docs. My idea of storage is that, initially the user will be able to use the app without signing up. Then, if he fancies he can create an account to sync the local data to the cloud. This way he can use another device and still have access to his data.
In the template there is AppSync.tsx and AppNonSync.tsx. What does it mean? Do I have to develop different version for local or cloud storage? Also the app decides which one to load based on a flag in sync.config.js. I thought I'd be able to change that at runtime, when the user decides to sign up.
I find the template rather confusing. Can you help me understand?
Edit 1:
I tried switching the flag to load the AppSync and now it requires me to sign in/up straight away (it's not looking "offline first").

The question is a bit broad but let me try to address it. Deciding how users authenticate is the first step. If anonymous authentication is used to allow the user to try the app, it can later be changed to email/password auth and can be linked to the original data. That's covered in the docs. Realm is an offline first database so the two templates show using it offline vs sync. You do not need to create two apps; If it's sync, then use the AppSyc template.

You're saying I should use AppSync because I plan on letting the user decide if he wants to sign up or not?

Not exactly. Assuming this app will utilize Atlas for cloud storage, you will need to implement the code for using Sync, and the AppSync has that code. If this were to be a local only App (not cloud storage) then you could go with the AppNonSync as local only is far simpler to implement.

Yeah that's what I meant: I would use AppNonSync only if I'm certain I'll never go cloud. And yes I'm planning on using Atlas for cloud.

I tried switching the flag to load the AppSync and now it requires me to sign in/up straight away that's correct! You're setting up a sync situation but to do that you'll either need to set up an account for sync'ing or use anonymous authentication. Did my comments above answer the question?

Yes I guess so. My take is that I need to use AppSync and set up anonymous authentication by default while giving the user the chance to sign up with a proper account.

Although, now that I think about it, it's not really an "offline first" approach since user data, although anonyomous, is still saved in the cloud and not on the device. Though I guess a better name for it would be "local first".

since user data, although anonyomous, is still saved in the cloud and not on the device - that's not how Realm works. It is always saved locally first then it will sync to the cloud "later", usually within milliseconds. That's the Offline First methodology - save local first, sync second.

Ah that's clear now thank you. Basically I was using the term "offline first" innapropriately. I thought it was more like "local storage until the user decides to go cloud". But it actually means "local storage until there's an internet connection to be able to upload to cloud".

Realm and the Realm SDK (now called Atlas Device SDK) is an offline first database, with the ability to Sync to the MongoDB Atlas server, which is 'cloud storage'.
With sync, Realm data is stored locally first, then automagically sync'd to Atlas later - usually within milliseconds as long as there's an internet connection.
The two files mentioned in the question demonstrate offline storage only (AppNonSync.tsx), often called "local only" and then sync'd storage (AppSync.tsx). Local only is far simpler to implement and is a great starting point when getting familiar with Realm. For example, this code is all that's needed to configure a local only Realm
import React from 'react';
import {RealmProvider} from '@realm/react';
function AppWrapperLocal() {
  return (
    <RealmProvider schema={[YourObjectModel]}>
      <RestOfApp />
    </RealmProvider>
  );
}

Sync setup requires more code and is covered in the documentation.
Anonymous authentication is one way to allow users to try the app, it can later be changed to email/password auth and can be linked to the original data. That's covered in the documentation.
You do not need to create two different versions; If it's sync, then use the AppSyc template. Noting that even Sync'ing is stored locally so you always have access to your data even when offline. Accessing sync'd data while offline is covered in the Access a Synced Realm While Offline
One thought is to make your trial version a local only app (which would not require authentication) - and when the user decides they like it when they sign up, their data becomes available on all their devices.
